# Disable comma in macros in C++

Tags: c++, c, macros

I have the following code of the json formatter for logs:

```
#define JLOG_INFO(value) LOG_INFO(LogJson{ { "level" : "info"}, (value) })
```

When I try to use it:

```
JLOG_INFO({"message", "Hello world"}, {"module", "base"});
```

I have the following error because of comma:

```
error: macro "JLOG_INFO" passed 4 arguments, but takes just 1 JLOG_INFO({"message", "Hello world"}, {"module", "base"})
```

How can I solve with problem with comma?

Comment: You really want to stop using macros for things like this...

Answer (score 3):

Use a variadic macro:

```
#define JLOG_INFO(...) LOG_INFO(LogJson{ { "level" : "info"}, __VA_ARGS__ })
```

---

Note that I removed the parenthesis around the parameter in the macro expansion.

Usually adding them is a good idea, but you must remember that they're not a magical incantation. They are included in the result of the macro expansion, and in this case they'd prevent the code from compiling.

Comment: But LOG_INFO get only one parameter. How can I join these parameters of the __VA_ARGS__ for only one?

Comment: @QuickDzen Preprocessor is dumb. It considers `,` to be argument separators, unless they're inside of parenthesis. Did you try this approach? It should work.